# jQuery UI draggable has jerky transition on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple drag and drop functionality that I'm attempting to get working. I have cards that are draggable and can be dropped on top of other cards to swap positions with the other card. Here's a fiddle with the functionality in place: https://jsfiddle.net/vj0a9gp8/1/

The drag and drop code is pretty simple:

```
$(function() {
  $(".card").  draggable({
    revert: true
  }).  droppable({
    hoverClass: "card-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      swapNodes($(this).get(0), $(ui.draggable).get(0));
    }
  });
});


function swapNodes(a, b) {
  var aparent = a.parentNode;
  var asibling = a.nextSibling === b ? a : a.nextSibling;
  b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
  aparent.insertBefore(b, asibling);
}
```

Basically when a card is dragged and then dropped onto another, the `swapNodes` function traverses up the dom and places them where they belong. This all works great. The issue, which you can see in the fiddle, is that when the drop occurs the dropped card kind of jerks off screen before animating in to place and it looks poorly overall. I've tried playing around with `draggable.position` to address and fix this functionality but all I've managed to do is make it worse. Any ideas?

Comment: would `overflow:hidden` on the `#board` help ? or do you want to change the animation ?

Comment: @Taki I don't think the `overflow:hidden` quite fixes it, it's the animation itself that is wonky. When the drop happens the element kinda jerks off in a direction before settling properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you drag your element, it changes the left and top position. When you drop it, you change its position in the DOM, but you never specify a new top and left, so it still keeps the one set when dragging it. The animation is there because you have a revert to true, which puts back the original position and animates it.

Easy solution would be to set revert to 'invalid' (so only if there's no drop) and set the left and top in your swap function. Like this

```
revert: 'invalid'
...
b.style.left = '';
b.style.top = '';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/huw2Lkgb/1/